# How to change color of image to one color in iText?

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I'm adding an image to a pdf document and I need to make the image the same color as the text. For example if the text color is green, the whole image also has to be green.

I tried searching online but didn't find any answer on how to change the color of an image in itext. I'm new to itext so I would really appreciate some help with this.

```
     var logo = Image.GetInstance(logoBytes);
     logo.PaddingTop = 0;
     var imageWidth = Convert.ToDouble(element.width) * Convert.ToDouble(element.scaleX);
     var imageHeight = Convert.ToDouble(element.height) * Convert.ToDouble(element.scaleY);
     var widthRatio = imageWidth / canvasWidth;
     var heightRatio = imageHeight / canvasHeight;
     var finalWidth = (float)envelopeWidth * 72 * ((float)imageWidth * 72 / 96) / (canvasWidth * 72 / 96);
     var finalHeight = (float)envelopeHeight * 72 * ((float)imageHeight * 72 / 96) / (canvasHeight * 72 / 96);
     var finalTop = (float)envelopeHeight * 72 * (element.top  * 72 / 96) / (canvasHeight * 72 / 96);
     var finalLeft = (float)envelopeWidth * 72 * (element.left * 72  / 96) / (canvasWidth * 72 / 96);
     var imageLeft = finalLeft + lpage.ArtBox.Left;
     envelopeBottom = lpage.ArtBox.Top + 40;
     var imageTop = envelopeBottom + (float)(envelopeHeight * 72) - Convert.ToDouble(finalTop) - finalHeight;
     logo.ScaleToFit((float)finalWidth, (float)finalHeight);
     logo.SetAbsolutePosition((float)imageLeft, (float)imageTop);
     doc.Add(logo);
```

I succeeded in making the text of the page the color I wanted but not the image.

Comment: Is the image black and white?

Comment: @mkl No. The image can be any color.

Comment: Then which colors shall be replaced by the text color and which colors shall be made transparent?

Comment: Have you meanwhile determined which colors shall be replaced by the text color and which colors shall be made transparent?